# Image searcher with facial recognition

Tags: gratis, search-engine, facial-recognition

I have never been impressed with Google's reverse image search and much prefer https://www.tineye.com/.

Ymmv, but I  wonder if there is an app (any platform/o.s, preferably gratis) which will take a photo of someone's face and search the internet for other photos of that person.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Alas, no. I seem to recall reading about some university doing it a few years ago, but have heard nothing since :-(   You coudl make a lot of money with it, if you cna develop it yourself ;-)

Comment: Thank you, yes, one could make a lot of money :)  I'm in the research phase of this..

Comment: I would be happy to alpha test :-)

Comment: Great, I'll keep that in mind!

Comment: I have time for that. Alas, I am too busy with side-project to help with the coding. But that leaves all of the money for you:-)

Comment: Maybe do some code reviews?  I'm hoping to use Delphi 10..

Comment: Sure, NP. I am currently on Delphi XE8, but looking to upgrade to 10. So long as you don't use any "for pay" VLC (I stopped paying for TmsSoftware).

Comment: I try to avoid paying for controls unless my customer requires it..

Comment: Agreed. However, I used to pay for https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmspack.asp and some of their other coimponents, which were useful across many projects. Anyone who can afford Delphi can probably afford those, although there are many excellent free VCL scomponents out there.

Comment: Looking at this library http://luxand.com/facesdk/  for recording facial data

Comment: luxland way to expensive.. $9,000 to $39,000.. it does handle what's required..

Comment: @JohnEasley did you get anywhere with your project?

Comment: we scrapped it, facial libraries too expensive.. may revisit at some point.

Comment: I notice that they don't have a price on the  web site - you have to ask for a quote. That generally $mell$ of ca$h.

Comment: Agree. I actually had discussion with them.. they wanted to know details of my project, and I provided a little information and was told those prices.  Let me know if you find a different library.. I would be interested in finding something more reasonable...

Comment: Perhaps related? [This](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-cam-video-streaming-face-recognition-arduino-ide/) has been on my to-do list for some time. Perhaps the libraries could be useful?